# Does Google Chart support UTF-8 Characters?

Tags: utf-8, google-visualization

I have title and labels with unicode labels in Google Chart, but they are not being displayed properly.

Here's an example: http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=300x225&cht=p3&chco=344566,C4C4C4&chds=0,90&chma=70,70&choe=UTF-8&chtt=Test&chd=t:27933485,20611682,34172068&chl=Un%E9%A7%85xbr%E1%83%A6cker|Test1|Test2

Characters do not appear right as you see.

Is there a way to make google charts display utf-8 characters properly? I've tried many things but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be the unicode codepoints (E9A785 -> 99C5 and E183A6 -> 10E6) that you are providing.  These characters do not appear to be displayed in a google chart.  Experiments with other codepoints (specifying them as UTF-8 in the same format as your query) appear to work fine.

The particular characters in your example (the first is from the CJK Unified Ideograms and the second from Georgian) are a little strange.  You might want to double check that they are correct.

Comment: What about this character, can it be displayed in Google charts: ★

Comment: Here's an example url with the star character in the title, doesn't work: http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=300x225&cht=p3&chco=344566,C4C4C4&chds=0,90&chma=70,70&choe=UTF-8&chtt=Te%E2%98%85%E2%98%85%E2%98%85st&chd=t:27933485,20611682,34172068&chl=Unix|Test1|Test2

Comment: Interestingly enough, adding some Chinese (?) chars to both title and legends fixes the issue: http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=300x225&cht=p3&chco=344566,C4C4C4&chds=0,90&chma=70,70&choe=UTF-8&chtt=Te%E2%98%85%E2%98%85%E2%98%85%E6%A0%87st&chd=t:27933485,20611682,34172068&chl=Unix|Test1|Test2%E6%A0%87